# `Current Library Version` emits a 32-bit truncation warning if version is higher than 16-bit max

Tags: xcode, ld, dylib

When setting the framework's `DYLIB_CURRENT_VERSION` larger than 65535 Xcode emits a warning:

> warning build: Truncating -current_version to fit in 32-bit space used by old mach-o format

Why would Xcode want to truncate versions that are larger than 16-bit max if the current version space is defined as 32-bit integer?

Is this a bug or is there some other setting to tweak in order for this warning to go away?

The Xcode version I am using is 14.0.1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because those 32 bits are split up:

```c
uint32_t version; /* X.Y.Z is encoded in nibbles xxxx.yy.zz */
```

That's from a different load command, but all 32-bit version fields in Mach-Os work that way. The highest version that can be represented by these is `65535.255.255`.

Also note that this may be "old" from the perspective of LLVM, but most structs and load commands in Mach-O headers still use 32-bit versions, with no alternative available, including the "current" and "compatibility" versions of dylibs. The only exception seems to be `LC_SOURCE_VERSION`/`struct source_version_command`, which uses a 64-bit field:

```c
uint64_t version; /* A.B.C.D.E packed as a24.b10.c10.d10.e10 */
```

Answer (score 0):

From the `ld` man page:

`-current_version number`

> Specifies the current version number of the library. The current version of the library can be obtained programmatically by the user of the library so it can determine exactly which version of the library it is using.  The format of number is X[.Y[.Z]] where X must be a positive non-zero number less
> than or equal to 65535, and .Y and .Z are optional and if present must be non-negative numbers less than or equal to 255.  If the version number is not specified, it has a value of 0.  This option is also called -dylib_current_version for compatibility.

In my case I triggered this warning by setting the version to `1.3.268`.

> -current_version 1.3.268

Since 268 is greater than 255 when I ran `otool` on my binary it capped at `255`.

```
$ otool -L /tmp/lib/libfoobar.dylib
    libfoobar.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.3.255)
                                                                        ^
```

This is why `ld` warns you about this. This could potentially cause confusion for users of your library.